# Build Normalization Function

Tags: python

I am stuck on a question for a course.

I have to build a normalization function. Here are the requirements:

- This function takes in the location of the data file, the attribute that has to be normalised (one of the values from 'Open','High','Low','Close','Volume', given as column indices) and the type of normalization to be performed ('min_max' or 'z_score')
- Based on the normalisation type that is mentioned, you will have to apply the appropriate formula and return a dictionary where key = original value in the dataset, value = normalised value
- A sample dataset has been provided to you at this location "./data/HistoricalQuotes.csv". Use this dataset to test the functionality you are building.

There are hidden test cases that are not passing when I submit my function but I am not getting any feedback so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This is my function that I created:

```py
def normalization (fname, attr, normType):
    '''
    Input Parameters:
        fname: Name of the csv file contiaining historical quotes
        attr: The attribute to be normalized 
        normType: The type of normalization 
    Output:
        a dictionary where each key is the original column value and each value is the normalised column value. 
    '''
    result = {}
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    select_column = df[attr]
    if normType == 'min_max':
        for x in select_column:
            result[x] = round((((x - min(select_column))/(max(select_column) - min(select_column))) * (1-0) + 0), 1)
    elif normType == 'z_score':
        for x in select_column:
            result[x] = round((x - np.mean(select_column))/ np.std(select_column), 1)
    return result
```

When I call the function with the sample data, it seems to be working properly. I can't figure out why it's not passing the hidden test cases.

Comment: As a side note, you should not recompute the min, max, mean and standard deviation for every loop.  Those are all constants.

Comment: One thing your function currently does not test is if the value `attr` provided as a function parameter is one of the possible options, 'Open', 'High', etc. Not sure if it is required, but this could be something to check, as it could be one of the hidden tests. Similarly, what if the `normType` is neither `min_max` nor `z_score`? But I guess in this case you can simply return an empty dictionary as you already do if not otherwise specified. You also round the result to only contain one decimal. Maybe check if this is correct.

Comment: Not sure exactly how min_max is being defined but I typically think of it as mapping the min value to 0 and max to 1.  This is not what your code is doing.  As an example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 9]` maps to `{1: -0.5, 2: -0.3, 3: -0.2, 4: 0.0, 9: 1.0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things in your code.
First I introduced the list called `attribute_type` to test if the provided value of parameter `attr` is within this list. If not I simply return the empty dictionary as we cannot change a column that is not defined, and we would encounter an error if we tried.

Next, as *Tim Roberts* stated, you recompute the values `mean, std, min, max` every time, which is not necessary as they do not change for the selected column. This is nothing major now, and I just included it to make you aware how to improve it. Instead of calling `min(select_column)` every time, you simply can use the `select_column.min()` function provided by Pandas.

Also, this is more important, with Pandas, you don't need to iterate over each column value with a `for` loop as you did.
Pandas provides functionality to use common operators such as plus, minus, and so on. So you simply declare the calculation as I did in the code, and Pandas will do the magic for you. Which is also way faster than calculating the values one by one.

After I changed that, I also introduced the variable `normalized_column_values` and instantiated it as an empty Pandas Series type.
Then I calculate either the `min_max` values or the `z_score` and right before the final `return result` statement, convert it to a dictionary.

I also changed the `round` function to allow two decimal values instead of one, as you will likely lose valuable information if you only use one decimal value. *Just think of trying to recalculate the original values based on the normalized values, min, max, mean and std. This is impossible if you cut off too much.*

Hope this helps and good luck with your assignment! :)

```
# Added attribute types to test attribute value in function
attribute_type = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

def normalization(fname: str, attr: str, normType: str) -> dict:
    '''
    Input Parameters:
        fname: Name of the csv file containing historical quotes
        attr: The attribute to be normalized 
        normType: The type of normalization 
    Output:
        a dictionary where each key is the original column value and each value is the normalised column value. 
    '''
    result = {}
    
    if attr not in attribute_type:
        # no need to continue as attribute is not defined
        return result
    
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    
    select_column = df[attr]
    
    
    normalized_column_values = pd.Series.empty
    
    if normType == 'min_max':
        normalized_column_values = ((select_column - select_column.min()) / (select_column.max() - select_column.min()))
        

    elif normType == 'z_score':
        normalized_column_values = (select_column - select_column.mean()) / select_column.std()
        
    else:
        return result
        
    result = {k:round(v, 2) for k,v in zip(select_column.values, normalized_column_values.values)}
        
    return result
```